# Nulleable parameter using route Data Annotations

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes

I send parameters from JS as:

```
apiService.post("../../api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/" + $scope.Codigo + "/" + $scope.Nombre + "/" + $scope.catalogoid + "/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/" + $scope.selected.ID
```

and I receive into controller like:

```
[Route("UpdateCatalogoRegistro/{Codigo}/{Nombre}/{ID}/{Padre}/{scopeSelected?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateCatalogoRegistro(HttpRequestMessage request, string Codigo, string Nombre, int ID, string Padre, int? scopeSelected)
```

As you can see I want to get nulleable `scopeSelected`. If I send all parameters into with postman as:

http://localhost:55720/api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/T60/T6000/4/MOD/2

it returns a value but If I delete last parameter as:

http://localhost:55720/api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/T60/T6000/4/MOD/

it throw me:

> "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:55720/api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/T60/T6000/4/MOD/'.",
>           "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'CatalogoRegistro' that matches the request."

It doesn´t found route. Why it dont detect nullable parameter? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the slash `/` at the end of the URL. The routing table does not know how to handle that segment.

Construct the URL accordingly when sending the request

```
var url = "../../api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/" + $scope.Codigo + "/" + $scope.Nombre + "/" + $scope.catalogoid + "/" + $scope.Catalogo;
if ($scope.selected.ID) { // or how ever you check for null
    url = url + "/" + $scope.selected.ID
}
apiService.post(url);
```

It is either that our check that the URL does not end with a trailing `/` before making the request and remove it.

```
var url = "../../api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/" + $scope.Codigo + "/" + $scope.Nombre + "/" + $scope.catalogoid + "/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/" + $scope.selected.ID;
apiService.post(url.trimRight("/"));
```

in the above case `trimRight("/")` is used to trim any trailing slashes on the end of the URL.